# p5.js "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" in flask app Raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am new to flask and javascript, but I am making an app using flask, p5.js and the "onoff" javascript library for controlling GPIO pins. when I run the app without the onoff library it works fine, however after I add the onoff library I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". I tried running the javascript file directly from the terminal and from there it works fine and it just stops working when I run it in the browser with the flask app.

Right now, since I am only testing, the code is supposed to print in console when the GPIO detects a pulse, however my plan is to make it change the value of the variable "idx" and "idy" with each pulse so that I can change the position of the circle drawn.

here is my code:

```
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio; //include onoff to interact with the GPIO

const pinInput = new Gpio(4, 'in', 'both'); //use GPIO pin 17 as input, and 'both' button presses, and releases should be handled
const w = 672;
const h = 504;

let canvas;
let idx = 0;
let idy = 0;
let Xcoords = [150, 541, 149, 541];
let Ycoords = [168, 175, 375, 376];

function setup() {
    canvas = createCanvas(w, h);
    canvas.parent("canvasHolder");
    noFill();
    stroke(255, 204, 0);
    strokeWeight(6);
  }
  
function draw() {
    ellipse(Xcoords[idx], Ycoords[idy], 40, 40);
}

pinInput.watch(function (err, value) { //Watch for hardware interrupts on pushButton GPIO, specify callback function
  if (err) { //if an error
    console.error('There was an error', err); //output error message to console
  return;
  }
  console.log(value);
  console.log("test print");
});

function unexportOnClose() { //function to run when exiting program
  pinInput.unexport(); // Unexport Button GPIO to free resources
};

process.on('SIGINT', unexportOnClose); //function to run when user closes using ctrl+c
}
```

if you need more information regarding my code please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs you are using depend on Node.js. They will **not** run in the browser.

(The specific error you are encountering is because `require` is part of the CommonJS module specification as implemented by Node.js but browsers don't support that).

It would be very dangerous if a malicious developer could tells any of their visitors' browsers to interact in arbitrary ways with the GIPO pins on their computers!

If you want to interact with them from a browser, then you need to do so using a web service.

You *could* write such a service using JavaScript running on Node.js, but since you already have Flask on the server side, it would make more sense to use [the Python equivalent](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio/python-rpigpio-api).

Comment: I just put it in a web service (apache2) and it still gives me the same error of require not being defined. Everything is running on local server (apache2)

Comment: A web **service** (not server) is a server side program accessed over HTTP. I was not suggesting that you serve the JS file (which requires Node.js to run) from a web server and continue to try to run it on a web browser (which is not Node.js and cannot run that JS).